# Missing var\lib directory in Windows when running Tomcat

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I am facing with an issue, when I am trying to run my app which runned on Linux server before. Now I am not able to edit code inside ROOT.war file, which was compiled earlier. When I am trying to run it locally now, it works, but the resources (data) are missing.

Data were stored in `var\lib\tancore` directory on linux server. Now I need to run it locally on Windows, but I am getting an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \var\lib\tancore\free.ser (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
        at my.vaadin.app.MyUI.deserializeData(MyUI.java:809)
        at my.vaadin.app.MyUI.init(MyUI.java:4942)
        at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:693)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:216)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
        at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:154)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:179)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1786)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

I am using apache-tomcat-9.0.87, tree result:

```
PS C:\Users\pcuser\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.87\apache-tomcat-9.0.87> tree
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows-SSD
Volume serial number is A85A-7F7C
C:.
├───bin
├───conf
│   └───Catalina
│       └───localhost
├───lib
├───logs
├───temp
├───var
│   └───lib
│       └───tancore
├───webapps
│   ├───docs
│   │   ├───annotationapi
│   │   ├───api
│   │   ├───appdev
│   │   │   └───sample
│   │   │       ├───docs
│   │   │       ├───src
│   │   │       │   └───mypackage
│   │   │       └───web
│   │   │           ├───images
│   │   │           └───WEB-INF
│   │   ├───architecture
│   │   │   ├───requestProcess
│   │   │   └───startup
│   │   ├───config
│   │   ├───elapi
│   │   ├───images
│   │   │   └───fonts
│   │   ├───jaspicapi
│   │   ├───jspapi
│   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   ├───servletapi
│   │   ├───tribes
│   │   ├───WEB-INF
│   │   │   └───jsp
│   │   └───websocketapi
│   ├───examples
│   │   ├───jsp
│   │   │   ├───async
│   │   │   ├───cal
│   │   │   ├───checkbox
│   │   │   ├───colors
│   │   │   ├───dates
│   │   │   ├───error
│   │   │   ├───forward
│   │   │   ├───images
│   │   │   ├───include
│   │   │   ├───jsp2
│   │   │   │   ├───el
│   │   │   │   ├───jspattribute
│   │   │   │   ├───jspx
│   │   │   │   ├───misc
│   │   │   │   ├───simpletag
│   │   │   │   └───tagfiles
│   │   │   ├───jsptoserv
│   │   │   ├───num
│   │   │   ├───security
│   │   │   │   └───protected
│   │   │   ├───sessions
│   │   │   ├───simpletag
│   │   │   ├───snp
│   │   │   ├───tagplugin
│   │   │   └───xml
│   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   ├───servlets
│   │   │   ├───images
│   │   │   └───nonblocking
│   │   ├───WEB-INF
│   │   │   ├───classes
│   │   │   │   ├───async
│   │   │   │   ├───cal
│   │   │   │   ├───checkbox
│   │   │   │   ├───colors
│   │   │   │   ├───compressionFilters
│   │   │   │   ├───dates
│   │   │   │   ├───error
│   │   │   │   ├───examples
│   │   │   │   ├───filters
│   │   │   │   ├───http2
│   │   │   │   ├───jsp2
│   │   │   │   │   └───examples
│   │   │   │   │       ├───el
│   │   │   │   │       └───simpletag
│   │   │   │   ├───listeners
│   │   │   │   ├───nonblocking
│   │   │   │   ├───num
│   │   │   │   ├───sessions
│   │   │   │   ├───trailers
│   │   │   │   ├───util
│   │   │   │   ├───validators
│   │   │   │   └───websocket
│   │   │   │       ├───chat
│   │   │   │       ├───drawboard
│   │   │   │       │   └───wsmessages
│   │   │   │       ├───echo
│   │   │   │       └───snake
│   │   │   ├───jsp
│   │   │   ├───lib
│   │   │   └───tags
│   │   └───websocket
│   ├───host-manager
│   │   ├───css
│   │   ├───images
│   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   └───WEB-INF
│   │       └───jsp
│   ├───manager
│   │   ├───css
│   │   ├───images
│   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   └───WEB-INF
│   │       └───jsp
│   └───ROOT
│       ├───META-INF
│       ├───VAADIN
│       │   └───themes
│       │       └───mytheme
│       └───WEB-INF
│           ├───classes
│           │   ├───my
│           │   │   └───vaadin
│           │   │       └───app
│           │   └───VAADIN
│           │       └───widgetsets
│           └───lib
└───work
    └───Catalina
        └───localhost
            ├───docs
            ├───examples
            ├───host-manager
            ├───manager
            └───ROOT
```

All necessary data should be inside `var\lib\tancore`, but Tomcat on Windows is not able to read it. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?